# ActiveMQ : Poor performances with large number of consumers on topic

Tags: performance, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms, jms-topic

I have a network of 2 non-persistent brokers which is dedicated to dispatch messages to 10000 different consumers using a single topic.
Each consumer use a topic selector to filter messages. The messages are produced by hundreds of producers : multiple Java/SpringBoot instances with a CachedConnexionFactory.

I have other queues and topics but it's not the point here.

My problem is that the more I have consumers on my topics, the more I have latency to deliver messages. I've designed a JMeter test suite to produce messages and measure performances easily, below the results :

- With no consumer on the topic : up to 10k msg/second can be delivered with good performances (max/average time in ms reported by Jmeter : 400/0,8).
  JMeter is not able to produce more messages, I can't measure performances with higher throughput.
- With 10K consumers : from 1k msg/second, poor performances (max/average time in ms reported by Jmeter : 30000/31). I have good performances with lower throughput

All my clients (producers and consumers) are connected on the 2 brokers using failover transport reference, so I don't know on which broker the messages will be produced to and I don't know on which broker a message need to be forwarded to be consumed.

You will find my config file here (http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/file/t379617/activemq.xml), and below some details about it :

- conduitSubscriptions=false on networkConnector : because I use topic selectors
- advisorySupport=false : because if true it doubles the number of consumers on my topic in a 2 nodes network scenario (i.e. : if I have 10K consumers, I will have 10K on each instance instead of 5K per instance), which impact negatively the performances
- All my topics and queues are "staticallyIncludedDestinations" : because dynamic require advisorySupport
- MaxPageSize=20000 on the topic policyEntry : it seems to be efficient. I think I need a large number to be able to evaluate a large amout of topic selector at the same time
- constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy=20 on the topic because I have a lot of consumers (20 x 10000 = 2000000 pending messages)
- The two brokers declare the same transport connector so it results in a duplex bridge between them.

My question is : why do I have so poor performances with many consumers, and how can I improve performances ?

I'm using ActiveMQ 5.15.3

Comment: I don't see a question here

Comment: Sorry. My question is : why do I have so poor performances with many consumers, and how can I improve performances ?

Comment: please note that ActiveMQ is TCP by default. So with 10K consumers, on the same topic, each message needs to be delivered 10k times, one-to-one. In other words if one consumer experiences 10k msg/second, the expectation is that with 10k consumers, each one only receives 1msgs/sec.